# Why my query doesn't update the table with my input parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, informix, parameterized-query

I don't know why the following query doesn't executed with my expected parameters !!

```
cmdTxt.Append("UPDATE sd32depart SET currentcredit = currentcredit + ? WHERE year = ? AND main_code = ? ");
paramList.Add("currentcredit", value.ToString().TrimEnd());
paramList.Add("year", year.ToString().TrimEnd());
paramList.Add("main_code", main_code.ToString().TrimEnd());
res = ConnectionObj.Execute_NonQueryWithTransaction(cmdTxt.ToString(), CommandType.Text, paramList);
```

I get

`res = 1`and although `currentcredit = 180` as a parameter

when i check my table i found `currentcredit NULL` !!

---

```
public int Execute_NonQueryWithTransaction(string cmdText)
            {
                string return_msg = "";
                int return_val = -1;
                //check if connection closed then return -1;
                if (connectionstate == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    return -1;
                command.CommandText = cmdText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Transaction = current_trans;
                try
                {
                    return_val = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (IfxException ifxEx)// Handle IBM.data.informix : mostly catched
                {
                    return_val = ifxEx.Errors[0].NativeError;
                    return_msg = return_val.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)// Handle all other exceptions.
                {
                    return_msg = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(return_msg))//catch error
                    {
                        //rollback
                        current_trans.Rollback();
                        Close_Connection();
                    }

                }
                return return_val;
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the Declarations of your objects (cmdTxt, paramList and res ?)

Comment: You are doing update so I guess you get number of rows affected

Comment: yeah i get `1` but the `currentcredit NULL` although i pass it `180`

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you calling `.ToString().TrimEnd()` on the values? In particular `value` and `year` - shouldn't they be left as-is (as correctly typed `int` / `decimal` / whatever)?

Comment: Also: what is your `Execute_NonQueryWithTransaction` method, and what does it do with `paramList` ? At the moment you're asking us to guess at your implementation to debug it...

Comment: @MarcGravell: this'sn't my code , i just try to refactor it and fix the bugs .i update my question.

Comment: Where is the commit of the transaction ?

Comment: That clearly isn't the right `Execute_NonQueryWithTransaction`, since it doesn't accept the parameter list or command-type. Please show the actual `Execute_NonQueryWithTransaction` method

Comment: Can you also clarify: what is the value of `currentcredit` in the database *before* the call? Because if it is `null`, it will remain `null`. `null + 180` => `null`

Comment: @MarcGravell : `currentcredit is null` before the update, what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> currentcredit is null before the update, what should i do

Ah, that's the problem then. In SQL, `null` is sticky. `null` + anything is: `null`. If this was TSQL (i.e. SQL Server), the solution would be `ISNULL`:

```
UPDATE sd32depart SET currentcredit = ISNULL(currentcredit,0) + ?
```

where the result of `ISNULL(x, y)` is `x` if `x` is non-null, otherwise `y`. In C# terms, it is the equivalent of `x ?? y` (and indeed, `ISNULL(x, y)` is identical to `COALESCE(x, y)`, except that `COALESCE` is *varadic*).

So: find the informix equivalent of `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`, and *use that*.

From a brief search, it seems that in informix [the `NVL` function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1002.htm) does this, so try:

```
UPDATE sd32depart SET currentcredit = NVL(currentcredit,0) + ?
```

Comment: @Mark Gravell but not all the time `currentcredit is null before the update` , sometimes it may have a number

Comment: @just_name which is fine; `NVL(currentcredit,0) + ?` will return the existing number if there is one.